# MS Dynamics CRM 4.0 - onChange event error

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, onchange, hidden-fields

I have an onChange event that keeps bringing up the error below whenever I preview it.

'Object doesnt support this property or method'

I have the onChange event associated with a picklist and when a specific option is selected another field is unhidden.

The code is below:

**onLoad:**

```
//If How did you hear about us is set to event show the Source Event lookup
crmForm.SourceEvent = function SourceEvent() 
{
if (crmForm.all.gcs_howdidyouhearaboutus.DataValue == 5)
{
crmForm.all.gcs_sourceeventid_c.style.display = '' ;
crmForm.all.gcs_sourceeventid_d.style.display = '' ;
}
else
{
crmForm.all.gcs_sourceeventid_c.style.display = 'none' ;
crmForm.all.gcs_sourceeventid_d.style.display = 'none' ;
}
}
crmForm.SourceEvent() ;
```

**onChange**

```
crmForm.SourceEvent() ;
```

Would be great if someone could let me know why this error is showing up?

Also, this has happened on a few onChange events on the form preview but once published onto the live system it does not error. Any ideas?

Thank you

Brett

Comment: What do you mean by when you "preview" it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding SourceEvent is not the supported way of doing that...

You should probably use the fire the `OnChange` event in the form load using `(if (crmForm.all.yourLookup) { crmForm.all.yourLookup.FireOnChange();}` and in the field's javascript `onChange` event write something like

```
var displayStyle = (crmForm.all.cf_picklist.DataValue == "3") ? "none" : "";
crmForm.all.cf_lookupid_d.style.display = displayStyle;
crmForm.all.cf_lookupid_c.style.display = displayStyle;
```

note that changing the Display CSS element is not supported, but it's the only way of doing that, without writing your own ASPX page.

ref: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31267662/hide-lookup-based-on-pick.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that either form elements with the "id" values you expect don't actually exist, *or* that you've used an "id" value more than once.

Also: that way of accessing elements will only work in IE.  Maybe that's what you want, but you can make it work in other browsers by using `document.getElementById()`

Comment: MSCRM is only supporting IE... so that shouldn't be a problem.